# Does this definition hold for uncountable spaces?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two commonly used definitions of Expected Value are $\mathbb{E}(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{x\in \mathbb{R}} x \text{P}(X=x)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \text{P}(X\geq x)$. I feel, using integration that they absolutely hold well that way. The basic definition I'm using is $\mathbb{E}(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega) \text{P}(\omega)$ where $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is the random variable.

I cannot prove the equivalence of these definitions for the uncountable case without using integration. I'd appreciate any proof or a hint that interprets this using indicator functions and show their equivalence. I posted a similar problem on Stack a day ago that is of a similar flavor; haven't received an answer yet. Perhaps these can help me a bit with the usage of indicators as well.

Comment: Where do you get these "definitions" from?

Comment: Idk, sort of everywhere. Take https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352884/equivalent-definitions-for-expected-value-of-random-variable as an exmaple

Comment: [Yes, it holds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value). But what do you mean by saying you want a proof "without using integration"? (An expected value *is* an integral.)

Comment: Oh right. I just meant, without showing it just for the continuous case. A quick question : For any $t \in \Omega$, $X(t)$ takes a single unique value, right? (as in, can $X$ be a multi-function ever?) I haven't come across such cases yet, so I was wondering if that is even a case in this topic.

Comment: A random variable is a *function*, so it takes only one value. Note that you can treat both the continuous and discrete cases in a unified way, via... integration: integration with respect to the corresponding measure (e.g., Lebesgue and counting).

Comment: Notice that in that question you link there is an objection to the uncountable sum in the comments. The definitions you write down do not make sense if taken literally (ok, the last one is correct if $\Omega$ is countable and we put a squiggly bracket around the $\omega$ inside the $P(\cdot).$)

Comment: Let the rv. $X$ be such that $P(X=\pi)=1$.  Then the formula $\sum_{x\in\mathbb R}P(X\ge x)$ evaluates to either $1$ or $\infty$, according to the OP's "definition", but the correct value of $E[X]$ is neither of these.

Comment: Because it's only for non-negative r.v.'s, and the sum in the uncountable (and countable, with the counting measure) case is an integral over $\mathbb{R}_+$. I missed that on my first reading of the OP's question...